# Why won't the scanf("%i%1[\n]", &a, &c) work?

Tags: c, scanf

Here, I wrote below code to parse hex string and convert it decimal format. In the `scanf` I add `char` type variable to store what parsed by format specifier `%[\n]` to debug the program.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(){
    int a;
    char c;

    while(true)
    {
        if(scanf("%i%1[\n]", &a, &c) != EOF)
        {
            printf("a = %d; c = %d", a, c);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

When I ran the compiled exective `test_scanf`, I got

```
$./test_scanf
0xff
a = 0; c = 10
```

From my understanding, `%i` will match `0xff` and `%1[\n]` will the `\n` (which is not shown in the input). Therefore, the result would be `a = 255; c = 10`. So what's wrong?

P.S. I run this code on Linux.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should always check the return value of `scanf` to match your expected number of arguments. You will not catch if only 1 or 0 parameters were parsed properly if you only check for `EOF`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I can reproduce the problem: https://ideone.com/oM1Irj and Williams comment solved the problem: https://ideone.com/MrEtWt

Answer (score 4):

You are invoking undefined behavior, because `%1[\n]` writes 2 bytes to the given address, but you have passed it an address that only has space for one.

Practially speaking, what is probably happening is that the `\n\0` that is being written to `&c` is overwriting the contents of `a` in the stack.  But it's not worth speculating about undefined behavior.  Anything can happen.  Avoid it.  Use `char c[2]` instead of `char c`. (And fix the call to `scanf` appropriately.)

Comment: why two bytes? \n is one character

Comment: All strings are null terminated.  `scanf` will read one byte and write 2.  It will write the `\n` and `\0` to terminate the string.

Comment: @alexis you're forgetting about the terminating character `\0`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another question. When I tried `scanf("%i%1[ ]", &a, &c)` -- a space in `[]`-- it worked. From my understanding, according the C language, a space in the format specifier will only match space. Hence the `\n` would be put back into the stream. In the next parse, `scan("%i%1[ ]", &a, &c) ` will try matching `%i` to `\n` and it would fail. But it worked well. Could you help to explain it?

Comment: Did it work well?  Or did `scanf` return 1 and not attempt to write anything to `c`?

Comment: Yes, it returned 1. But I input serval groups of hex data by pressing Enter after each of them, then every hex is parsed successful. So, are the `\n` among them dismissed?

Comment: `scanf` is not consuming the `\n` with `%1[ ]` because it does not match the conversion specifier.  But `%i` consumes leading whitespace, so the `\n` is consumed by it.

Comment: Thanks again. After testing the code and read the [scanf in cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/), it's right that `%i` does consume leading whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

The `1` in `"%1[\n]"` is a *width limit*, up to 1 character is read and saved in `&a`.

`"%1[\n]"` forms a *string* when successfully done by appending a *null character*.  Unfortunately the destination only has room for one - leading to *undefined behavior* (UB).

`"%1[\n]"` does not read anything nor append a null character is the first character is not a `'\n'`.  Scanning stops.  Non-matching input remains in `stdin`.

Best to test `scanf()` for the number of conversions desired, not against `EOF`.

```
// char c;
char c[2];

while(true) {
    // if(scanf("%i%1[\n]", &a, &c) != EOF) {
    if(scanf("%i%1[\n]", &a, c) == 2) {
        printf("a = %d; c = %d", a, c);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```